# How to associate an image folder with an xml file with the names of the images?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing

Suppose I have an image folder with 3 images 1, 2, 3 and an XML file which has the names for these images.

The XML file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
-<imagelist>
  <image tag="self" file="word/1/1.jpg"/>
  <image tag="adhesive" file="word/1/2.jpg"/>
  <image tag="address" file="word/1/3.jpg"/>
</imagelist>
```

How do I read this in Python or particularly in pandas so as to associate the image with its image tag in the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using minidom

**Demo:**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse(filename)
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('image')
for i in itemlist:
    print(i.attributes["file"].value)
```

**Output:**

```
word/1/1.jpg
word/1/2.jpg
word/1/3.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

**Demo:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
dom = ET.parse(xmlfilename)
for element in dom.findall('image'):
   print(element.get('file'))
```

**Output:**

```
word/1/1.jpg
word/1/2.jpg
word/1/3.jpg
```